# WinUI 3 C++/WinRT loading string resources

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, winui-3

I have a basic WinUI3 C++/WinRT app, containing a resw file with a simple entry named "APPNAME".  I wish to put that string in the title of my Xaml form.

My MainWindow.xaml.cpp has this snippet of code in it.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        auto resourceLoader{ Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::ResourceLoader::GetForViewIndependentUse()};
        hstring title = resourceLoader.GetString(L"APPNAME");
        this->Title(title);

    }
```

The issue seems to be that "Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources" isn't correct. So the question becomes how to access that resw string entry in C++/WinRT?

Many thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With WinUI 3, most namespaces usually start with `Microsoft`, instead of `Windows` (which was more for UWP).

It's actually difficult to get to the WinUI3-only documentation, here is some: [Manage resources with MRT Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/mrtcore/mrtcore-overview)

The WinUI 3 resource entry point is now the [Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceManager class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.windows.applicationmodel.resources.resourcemanager).

So, for a "*MyString*" string resource in a "*Resources.resw*" file

[image]

You can now do this:

```
Microsoft::Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::ResourceManager rm{};
auto str = rm.MainResourceMap().GetValue(L"Resources/MyString").ValueAsString();
```

Note that you need to `#include <winrt/Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.h`> after Xaml includes to compile.