# How do I access Resources.resw strings in a Winui3 TemplateStudio app

Tags: string, resources, winui-3

The WinUI for Desktop Template Studio template contains a file Resources.resw file in the project folder Strings/en-us. The ShellPage has XAML Uid properties which map to keys in this file for navigation page titles. I am trying to store other localized strings in this file and access them in code.

I am using the following code to extract the string when a particular page is loaded:

```
public sealed partial class TransactionDetailPage : Page
{    
    public TransactionDetailPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            var rl = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
            App.CurrentPageTitle = rl.GetString("TransactionDetailPage.Title");
        };
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following runtime error and despite much googling have been unable to find a solution.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
Resource Contexts may not be created on threads that do not have a CoreWindow. (0x80073B27)
```

I would appreciate any help solving this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WinUI 3 C++/WinRT loading string resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628384/winui-3-c-winrt-loading-string-resources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Template Studio should create this class:

**ResourceExtensions.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources;

namespace TemplateStudioWinUI3LocalizerSampleApp.Helpers;

public static class ResourceExtensions
{
    private static readonly ResourceLoader _resourceLoader = new();

    public static string GetLocalized(this string resourceKey) => _resourceLoader.GetString(resourceKey);
}
```

so you should be able to:

```cs
Loaded += (s, e) =>
{
    App.CurrentPageTitle = "TransactionDetailPage.Title".GetLocalized();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works except that the key string should not contain a period ('.') otherwise it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

A slight adjustment to the answer by @Andrew KeepCoding to allow for shorter keys when looking for localized resources defined in the calling assembly:

I use the `ResourceManager` instead of `ResourceLoader` so that I can access the main resource map as well as any other sub-map within the application.

```cs
using Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources;

public static class ResourceExtensions
{
    private static readonly ResourceMap Strings = new ResourceManager().MainResourceMap;

    public static string? GetLocalized(this string? value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return value;
        }

        var localized = Strings.TryGetValue(value);
        return localized != null ? localized.ValueAsString : value;
    }

    public static string? GetLocalizedMine(this string? value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return value;
        }

        var assemblyName = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        var subMap = Strings.GetSubtree($"{Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name}/Strings");
        if (subMap == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Resource map for assembly `{assemblyName}` does not exist.");
            return value;
        }

        var localized = subMap.TryGetValue(value);
        return localized != null ? localized.ValueAsString : value;
    }
}
```